# How to translate "statistical significance" and "statistical meaningfulness" to Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

"Statistical significance" is a very well known concept in statistics, but "statistical meaningfulness" is not that much, this concept has different names, sometimes depending on the field of application, i.e. in the medical field, this concept is known as "clinical significance"

Comment: Please note that the -ness suffix in English can translate as estado or condición.

Answer (score 2):

The usual translation of statistical significance into Spanish is [significación estadística](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significaci%C3%B3n_estad%C3%ADstica) as confirmed by that link to Wikipedia. I have never seen the phrase statistical meaningfulness used in English. There are concepts like the [minimal clinically important difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_important_difference) which is Spanish would be *diferencia mínima clínicamente importante*. It is widely used in planning studies in health.

Comment: Well, something can be statistically meaningful. So the ness is just the state or condition of being meaningful.

Comment: @Lambie that is perfectly true. Although it is off-topic here there has been a long battle in health research to emphasise the difference between statistically significant and clinically important and I felt that statistically meaningful was blurring an important distinction and as I said I have no memory of reading it.

Answer (score 0):

No conozco los términos. El primero es **significación estadística** y mide la correlación entre dos magnitudes. El segundo supongo que sería la **relevancia**, el **aporte** o el **valor** que el experimento aporta de por sí. Relevancia estadística? Valor estadístico? Podría ser, lo mejor es buscar cómo figua en algún libro que ya esté traducido, pero si no hay ninguno tenés mis sugerencias.